# SELECT statement with if ELSE in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table looks like this:

```
 ref     doc 
 -----------
 ref001   3
 ref001   3 
 ref002   1 
 ref002   4 
 ref002   1
```

I want to use `SELECT` with `IF ELSE` statement or any other conditional statement similarly to this idea:

```
SELECT MAX(ref), THEN SELECT IF MAX(doc)) OR ELSE SUM(doc)
```

Sample output:

```
  ref001  3
  ref002  6
```

Comment: i believe what you are looking for is CASE statements

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're asking. `MAX(ref)` would definitely give you `ref002`, and `ref=ref` is always true...

Comment: `if (ref = ref)` will always be true, so it's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want distinct `ref` number with `doc` number is the following condition (as per the output shown).
If the all the existing `doc` numbers are same for a `ref` number, then get `max(doc)` otherwise `sum(doc)`.

```
SELECT  ref,
        (CASE WHEN MAX(doc) = MIN(doc) THEN MAX(doc) ELSE SUM(doc) END) AS doc
FROM    table1
GROUP BY ref
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple aggregations to do that:

```
select ref,
    case when min(doc) = max(doc)
         then max(doc) else sum(doc) end doc_total
from t
group by ref;
```